# Regular Expression checking for numeric length

Tags: regex

I want to validate a zipcode either 5 digit or 9 digit.
I've written this  `/^(\d){5|9}$/` but its not matching anything.

But when i give `/^(\d){5}$/` its matching properly for 5.

Please help.

Comment: had the same answer ... but just wanted to submit a tip .. http://rubular.com/ is great for testing most regex stuff online.

Comment: okay but I'm testing my regex on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the last four optional:

```
^\d{5}(\d{4})?$
```

Note that I removed the opening/closing slashes as they have nothing whatsoever to do with regex; they are an application language artefact.

Answer (score 6):

The following regex should work.

```
^(\d{5}|\d{9})$
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Matching USPS ZIP+4

If you're dealing with the US Postal Service's ZIP+4 format, this regular expression might provide more accurate matches:

```
egrep -o '\b[[:digit:]]{5}-?[[:digit:]]{4}?\b'
```

#### Corpus

This regular expression was tested against a limited corpus. Your mileage may vary.

```
cat << EOF | egrep -o '\b[[:digit:]]{5}-?[[:digit:]]{4}?\b'
    12345
    123456789
    12345-6789
EOF
```